# how to check true condition in iCanHaz (Moustache Template engine)

Tags: javascript, templating-engine, icanhaz.js

I've this json return

```
data = [
    {   firstName: "Christophe",
        lastName: "Coenraets"},
    {   firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Smith"}
];
```

I want to display each object in a `li` list and want to use `Enumerable` condition. I understand if it'd been like

```
data = { elem :[
        {   firstName: "Christophe",
            lastName: "Coenraets"},
        {   firstName: "John",
            lastName: "Smith"}
]};
```

I can use something like

```
{{#elem}}
    <li>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</li>
{{/elem}}
```

But in the first case, how do I check the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't work with icanhaz, it very well may have a method to parse the data that you get, but you could always modify the JSON object and wrap it into a parent element like in your second case:

```
myData = { elem : data};
```